# Prove infinity arithmatics

Tags: calculus, infinity

How do you prove $ \infty * (-\infty) = -\infty$ or $ \infty +\infty = \infty$?
I thought it is an axiom, but have been there's is proof for that.

Comment: You have to first define $\infty$ either as a closure of $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}=[-\infty,\infty]$ or as a limit.  Your choice will give you the tools for prove it.

Comment: as a limit please

Comment: Then you need to show that $a_n\to +\infty$, $b_n\to -\infty$ implies $a_nb_n\to-\infty$ etc. (Then again, you still need to remark that yo will accept this as proof because you want to employ the *permanence principle* accordingly)